# ControlsFX 8.0.6 dialogs java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java, javafx, bundle, controlsfx

I'm a new user of ControlsFX and I have an issue that I don't understand:

My code:

```
Dialogs.create()
    .owner(mainStage)
    .title("Information Dialog")
    .masthead("Test masthead")
    .message("Test message")
    .showInformation();
```

And I obtain an exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name impl.org.controlsfx.dialog.resources.oxygen.dialog-resources, locale fr_FR
```

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the right JAR ? Aka this: [ControlsFX-8.0.6](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-8.0.6.zip)

Because I'm made this simplest program with the JAR I specified and I got no errors:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;


public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Dialogs.create()
                .owner(primaryStage)
                .title("Information Dialog")
                .masthead("Test masthead")
                .message("Test message")
                .showInformation();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Please also consider to raise your question in the official group support here : http://groups.controlsfx.org , you'll likely have more answers.

Comment: I've tried your code with the right version of ControlsFX (fresh download) and I obtain the same message...
I'll post a message in the official group support.
Thank you.